# in Scala using RDD , how do you get apply function in the Iterable if RDD[(k,Iterable[v])

Tags: scala, rdd

I am trying to figure a way to efficiently apply filters (multiple) on the Iterable[Value] for a given  RDD[Key,Iterable[Value]] class.

The reason being is I want to filter the RDD and eventually find the keys that match the filter

Example of RDD

```
 000473643-02,CompactBuffer((glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0), (glucose2,80.0),   (fasting blood glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0)))
 (713003448-01,CompactBuffer((glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0)))
 (000023838-01,CompactBuffer((glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0)))
 (000772974-01,CompactBuffer((glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0)))
 (380670000-01,CompactBuffer((glucose,80.0), (glucose,80.0)))
```

So in this case, I need to output the Key only when the the following is true:

```
    glucose value is >= 80 or fasting blood glucose >= 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
case class ExceedsCondition(threshold:Double) {
  def violates(value:Double) = value >= threshold
}

val conditionsBroadcast = sc.broadcast(
  Map("glucose" -> ExceedsCondition(80.0), 
      "fasting-glucose" -> ExceedsCondition(81.0))
  )

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("key1" -> List(("glucose" -> 83.0))))

val result = rdd.filter { case (_, xs) =>
            val conditions = conditionsBroadcast.value
            xs.exists { case (key, value) =>
                conditions.get(key).exists(_.violates(value))
            }
}

result.take(10)
```

Comment: the broadcast does an OR of all condition, is there a way to do AND of all condition  and secondly can we do different conditions .. like one doing > and the other >= in one conditionsBroadcast statement or I need to do several passes on the same RDD   When I tried different conditions I get the error :         error: value violates is not a member of Product with Serializable
              xs.exists { case (key, value) => conditions.get(key).exists(_.violates(value)) } }      @vitalii

Comment: Oh by the way, I forgot to ask, the conditions above means the conditions are all OR .. is there a possibility to do it with different set of conditions (<, >=. <=) on one conditions class.. and is there a way to have AND instead of OR @vitalii